# I need to retrieve current date with help of TSQL query

Tags: t-sql

I'm newer in T-SQL.So maybe my question will seem naive.

I need to retrieve current date with help of TSQL query.

I can implement this by `GETDATE()` function but the function

returns me this format **04-03-2012 13:58:02**,

I need to get only the date without hour minute and seconds.

Any idea how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will remove the time from the `datetime` object. Therefore it will be in the format `04-03-2012 00:00:00`

```
DECLARE @d datetime
SET @d = GETDATE()
SET @d = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @d))

SELECT @d
```

---

If you wish to not send any time back at all, then this is not strictly a `datetime` object, and you should pass it as a string:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
```

Personally however, I would always send back the value as a `datetime` object, and then format the date at application level. Once a date is converted to a string, its bad practice to try and convert this back to a date, and could cause you problems later down the line.

Comment: 04-03-2012 00:00:00 can i remove the part of hours(00:00:00)?

Comment: @Michael Please see the second part of my answer for removing `00:00:00`